# Generate weakly connected components as new graph in Networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have the graph `G`. I want to display its largest weakly connected component as a separate graph and get the its number of edges and nodes.

I think the `weakly_connected_component_subgraphs` ([Doc](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.weakly_connected.weakly_connected_component_subgraphs.html)) function can solve my problem. [But deprecated in NetworkX 2.1](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/release_2.4.html). what is the alternative of this function in NetworkX 2.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you found some missing document for [`weakly_connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.weakly_connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.weakly_connected_components) as the hint you are looking for is only present in [`connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components):

```py
S = [G.subgraph(c).copy() for c in connected_components(G)]
# or in your case
S = [G.subgraph(c).copy() for c in weakly_connected_components(G)]
```